# C# nameof into strongly typed parameter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using entity framework, I have an entity called permissions, which has a set of `bool`s to specify what can and can't be done.

A little bit like:

```
public class Permissions
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int GroupId {get;set;}
   public bool ViewRecords {get;set;}
   public bool EditRecords {get;set;}
   public bool DeleteRecords {get;set;}
   public bool CreateRecords {get;set;}
   public bool CreateSubGroups {get;set;}
}
```

You get the idea. Each user group has one of these and that's all good.

I have a security services class which validates and checks this information against the right group and action - again, all working well - however I'm left with some magic strings which I'd like to avoid.

For example: `public bool HasPermission(int groupId, string action)`

I'd like as: `public bool HasPermission(int groupId, Permission action)`

At the moment, I'm using `nameof`, so:

```
bool go = HasPermission(123, nameof(Permission.ViewRecords));
```

However, is there a way to map the class properties so it would be:

```
bool go = HasPermission(123, Permission.ViewRecords);
```

I could do it with an enum, and maintain the two to mirror each other, but that is an overhead I'd like to avoid - and whilst nameof works, the fact is the method can receive any string and therefore could be broken later down the line.

Comment: Why not use an enum?  It's not that much overhead and it prevents it being broken by someone passing an unknown magic string down the line.

Comment: The other advantage of an enum is that you can make it a flags enum and check for multiple permissions rather easily.

Comment: @StephenWilson that's wy I ask - whilst it's not a massive overhead I try to minimise the number of changes required when (invariably) a new permission is added later down the line. Now a perfectly valid answer is just that - "No, a enum is a good thing(tm)". WIth @Servy's point about `flags` (new one for me there), an `Enum` becomes more compelling!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd simply create a method `GetPermission` (if you don't have one yet):

```
Permissions GetPermission(int groupId) { ... }
```

and then use it like this:

```
if (GetPermission(123).ViewRecords) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks pretty much a better way - I'll try it out as I'll need to refactor a bit and there're some extra dimensions being checked as part of the function - it's a user group as well as an organisation group matrix, but that would have muddied the question!

Comment: As per the comments in the question, I've gone with an `enum` for the other benefits, plus the model means that a user can belong to multiple groups (not clear from the question however), and the permissions can be taken from any group... However this is a great answer for the question, and a great way to look at simpler permissions models!

Answer (score 1):

This is not my code, but i can't remember from where i got it.

```
public bool HasPermission(int groupId, Expression<Func<T>> propertySelector)
{
    if (propertyExpresssion == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpresssion");
    }

    var memberExpression = propertyExpresssion.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The expression is not a member access expression.", "propertyExpresssion");
    }

    var property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (property == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The member access expression does not access a property.", "propertyExpresssion");
    }

    var getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(true);
    if (getMethod.IsStatic)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The referenced property is a static property.", "propertyExpresssion");
    }

    var name = memberExpression.Member.Name;
}
```

You can call it with:

```
bool go = HasPermission(123, () => Permission.ViewRecords);
```

Comment: This is just a long way of writing nameof(...).  Why rewrite something that is in the C# language.  This is ok for version 5 or older of C#.  And I think Miguel Castro used this code in one of his Pluralsight courses.

Comment: This is not a direct rewrite of nameof(). He wanted a way to give a method a property and don't write nameof() around the property. And as you stated, it works in older versions too.